# viewForHeaderInSection: not called when reloadData: is called

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I made a `UITableView` and set the "delegate" and "datasource" and every time I call `reloadData`, it goes into the method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.headersList count];
}
```

And the method:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    SectionInfo *headerInfo = (self.headerInfoArray)[section];
NSInteger numOfObjectsInSection = [[headerInfo.list objectsInList] count];
    return headerInfo.open ? numOfObjectsInSection : 0;
}
```

And then stops! it doesn't go into the `ViewForHeaderInSection:` method. I have also implemented the method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return SECTION_HEADER_HEIGHT;
}
```

- Knowing that I use the open/close section feature! so at first all the sections are closed and the number of rows in each one is 0 but the number of sections returned is correct (when a section is opened the number of rows is updated).
- The only way for it to show the header views is to wait for some time until it's automatically reloaded! or I swipe up or down!

The `viewForHeaderInSection` method:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UISectionHeaderView *sectionHeaderView = [[UISectionHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, SECTION_HEADER_HEIGHT)];

    SectionInfo *sectionInfo = (self.headerInfoArray)[section];
    sectionHeaderView.open = sectionInfo.open;
    sectionInfo.headerView = sectionHeaderView;

    sectionHeaderView.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%lu)",sectionInfo.list.title, (unsigned long)[sectionInfo.list.objectsInList count]];
    sectionHeaderView.section = section;
    sectionHeaderView.delegate = self;

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: I assume that you set your class both as the `dataSource` and the `delegate` of your `UITableView`, right?

Comment: You can also use the reload section methods to try a different approach. show us your table view header and footer view datasource callbacks to see if there's an issue there.

Comment: yah, there is nothing wrong with the dataSource and delegate. This behavior only happens when all the sections are closed.

Comment: @J2theC do you mean the ViewForHeaderInSection: method ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yah didn't work

Comment: My understanding is that the delegate methods `heightForHeaderInSection:` and `viewForHeaderInSection:` are called as required - that is - when a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` needs a section and row to display the `UITableViewCell`. If you are setting your the number of rows in a section to zero, I would expect that these delegate methods are not called. I have not used the section open/close feature before, so I may be off the mark here, but have you tried always returning the appropriate number of rows (never zero) and then closing the section in your delegate method/s?

Comment: I'm keeping this as a last resolve! in the apple example for the open/close section feature If I remember correctly they were returning 0 as well for the rows at first and the delegate methods still got called!

This is the link for the apple example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I am having this issue as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538416/nsfetchedresultscontroller-does-not-call-viewforheader-upon-reloaddata

Comment: AM having the same issue!! and interesting to note is that the apple example does NOT implement heightForHeaderInSection and still works fine.

Comment: the only difference i can think of is that I/You have used a UITableView, while the apple example has used UITableViewController

Comment: I am having this exact same issue as well. Very weird behaviour not consistent with "normal" UITableView. I only tried it on iOS7 though, not sure if it is happens on iOS8 too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should implement `heightForHeaderInSection:` and set the height for the header to a value > 0.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue occured with me that's because **tableview** didn't find **height** for header but as I was using **automatic height calculation** from **xCode 9**, I cannot give any explicit height value. After some experimentation I **got solution**, we have to override this method as,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return 44.0f;
}
```

Although I have **checked** both options

1. **Automatic Height Calculation**
2. **Automatic Estimated Height Calculation**

from **storyboard** as apple says, but still I got this weird error.

**Please Note**: This Error was shown only on **IOS-10** version not on **IOS-11** version. Maybe it's a bug from xCode. Thanks